# Which school is the one that Claude Debussy studied in?

Tags: history, where-are-they-now

I am confused about the school that Debussy studied in in Paris. I searched in wiki it said he studied in the school which now called CNSMDP. But in some other websites said his school now located in 14 Rue de Madrid, which is the address of CRR de Paris. Both these two school have a old name Paris Conservatory. So which one is the one Debussy studied in?

Or there is other address of Debussy's school.

Answer (score 3):

Débussy studied at the Paris Conservatoire from 1872 (when he was aged 10) for 11 years.

At that time the Conservatoire was in a street which then was named "Rue Bergère", now renamed "Rue du Conservatoire".

In 1911 the Conservatoire moved to 14, Rue de Madrid  - [(information here)](http://crr.paris.fr/Histoire.html), now home to the [CRR (Convervatoire à Rayonnment Régional de Paris)](http://crr.paris.fr/CRR_de_Paris.html).

In 1990, it moved again to its present location at La Villette, where it is known as the "Conservatoire national supérieur de musique et de danse de Paris" (CNSMDP).

The former Paris Conservatoire building, where Débussy would have studied, is now the home of the  "Conservatoire national supérieur d'art dramatique" (CNSAD),  Street address: 
2 bis, Rue du Conservatoire, 75009 Paris, France.
[CNSAD wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNSAD)
[Conservatoire website (french)][1]

References:

- [Conservatoire_de_Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatoire_de_Paris).
- [Conservatoire de Paris
  history](http://www.conservatoiredeparis.fr/en/lecole/histoire/)